# Flutter: Save Lists local

Tags: list, flutter, save, storage

. Hello, I want that my program save my lists locally, that when ever the App gets startet the list gets load and with every new entry the list gets saved .(Delete/Remove Funktion should save the list to). I search on the Internet but no one show it excatly how I want. I hope someone can help me.

Edit: I also would like to know how to save a bool

Here the List and under that the Button to add Input from a Textfield to the list

````
 class TimescheduleData {
  static List<String> time = [];

  static List<String> who = [];
  static List<String> when = [];
  static List<String> where = [];
} ```

TextButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check_circle_outline_rounded,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: 120,
                ),
                
                  TimescheduleData.time.add(myControllertime.text);
                  TimescheduleData.who.add(myControllerwho.text);
                  TimescheduleData.when.add(myControllerwhen.text);
                  TimescheduleData.where.add(myControllerwhere.text);
                  myControllertime.clear();
                  myControllerwho.clear();
                  myControllerwhen.clear();
                  myControllerwhere.clear();
                  Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => App()));
                })

void deleteDate(int Index) {
    setState(() {
      TimescheduleData.time.removeAt(Index);
      TimescheduleData.when.removeAt(Index);
      TimescheduleData.where.removeAt(Index);
      TimescheduleData.who.removeAt(Index);
    });
  }


GestureDetector(
  onDoubleTap: () => deleteDate(Index),
````

Comment: You can find everything you need in this cookbook https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite Instead of Dog object you need to define your own model with all those feilds. So that you have to maintain single list instead of 4 strings. Same mentioned in answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582978/7910735

Answer (score 0):

In order to save lists or anything locally you need some way to persist data. There are multiple options out there. Depends if you need heavy relational models or just some data to store.

I've used Hive before and it's a great databse (key, value based). But you also have SQL options and shared_preferences that is also key value based but simpler than hive.

Here is a great article by codemagic that explains the options

https://blog.codemagic.io/choosing-the-right-database-for-your-flutter-app/